# PayPal notify_url not being called after extensive sandbox testing

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm designing a website for a charity board game event, wherein people can watch the event live, and can donate money to a charity (Child's Play) in order to force players to play continuously for 60 hours.  Because the donations are going directly to Child's Play, I need to use the notify_url setting to pass my IPN notification URL in; we've done this marathon twice before and have had no problems, but we recently ported it over to PHP.

Now, I've been testing the site extensively for the past few months using the sandbox, and everything was working perfectly.  The marathon is only a couple of weeks away now, so I switched over to the actual PayPal system, fired off a test donation, and now I've got a problem: for some reason, PayPal is not hitting the notify_url at all.  I've verified the URL by switching back to sandbox temporarily, and everything works fine.  I've also added a few calls to error_log in the listener code to see if it's just getting caught in the code somewhere, but have found out it hasn't been hit at all.

If anyone can offer any suggestions here as to what I can do, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Obviously I'm under a bit of a time crunch, so I'd really appreciate it if you could respond sooner rather than later.

EDIT: Here's the relevant code:

```
if (isset($_GET['paypalipn'])) {
  // tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
  ini_set('log_errors', true);
  ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

  // intantiate the IPN listener
  $listener = new IpnListener();

  // tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
  $listener->use_sandbox = false;

  error_log("here");

  // try to process the IPN POST
  try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
  }

  error_log("here2");

  // Process the IPN
  if ($verified) {

      error_log("here3");

      $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

      // Split the custom variable
      $split_custom = explode("&", $_POST['custom']);
      $custom_array = array();
      for ($i = 0; $i<count($split_custom); $i++) {
        $current_set = explode("=", $split_custom[$i]);
        $custom_array[$current_set[0]] = $current_set[1];
      } 

      error_log("here4");

      if (!isset($custom_array['game'])) {
        $custom_array['game'] = 0;
      }
      if (!isset($custom_array['player'])) {
        $custom_array['player'] = 0;
      }

      error_log("here5");

      if (!empty($errmsg)) {

          // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking
          $body = "IPN failed fraud checks: \n$errmsg\n\n";
          $body .= $listener->getTextReport();
          mail('jafawcett@gmail.com', 'IPN Fraud Warning', $body);

      } else {

          mail('jafawcett@gmail.com', 'Successful IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
      }

      error_log("donor_un: ".$custom_array['donor_un']);
      process_donation($_POST['mc_gross'], $custom_array['player'], $custom_array['game'],     $custom_array['donor_name'], $_POST['payer_email'], $custom_array['donor_un']);

  } else {
      // manually investigate the invalid IPN
      mail('jafawcett@gmail.com', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
  }

}
```

For the ipn listener class I'm using the one created by Micah Carrick and available here:
https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: Sorry, pressed submit a bit to quickly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked my direct contact at PayPal about this and got the following response...

> In regards to the IPN issue, we had an outage last night. It was fixed
>   at about 1-2am, the IPN’s are delayed because we had a backed up queue
>   of about 2.5 million IPN’s which did not send out. We are currently
>   working through these IPN’s. I’d expect normal functionality shortly.

You can also see plenty of people talking about [this issue on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=paypal%20down).

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same problem.

It worked perfectly fine for a few months now and the script remains untouched. PayPal IPN is enabled inside the PayPal account as well and our IPNs just stopped this morning.

There might be a problem over at PayPal, we're still trying to figure it out.